# How to \immediate\write with multiple lines?

Tags: expansion, write

Using LuaLaTeX with TeXlive 2016, although I imagine that this question applies to nearly anything:

I know how to create a file using `\immediate\write` on a line-by-line basis. But I would like to do it for multiple lines, where the number of lines is not known in advance (it is the result of gathering text items in a macro). Something like this:

```
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=pickafilename.txt
\immediate\write\file{Hello! I am a new file.}
\immediate\write\file{\MacroContainingTextMacros}
\closeout\file
```

The `\MacroContainingTextMacros` has a few small macros within it, which I wish to expand as the file is written. Each of those small macros contains a few lines of plain text. So I cannot use verbatim, or `filecontents`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to write the `\newlinechar` which is pre-set to be `^^J` in latex.

```
\def\MacroContainingTextMacros{
aa^^Jbb^^Jcc}
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=pickafilename.txt
\immediate\write\file{Hello!^^JI am a new file.}
\immediate\write\file{\MacroContainingTextMacros}
\closeout\file

\stop
```

produces

```
Hello!
I am a new file.
 aa
bb
cc
```

Comment: So simple! I always wondered what `^^J` meant. I see it in code. I thought maybe it was a programmer's Smiley Face.

Comment: @RobtA it is control J that is ascii 10 (line feed), the `^^` is primitive TeX syntax for shifting the character code by 64 (which is what ctrl does, more or less)

Comment: I bet you could get away with using `^^M` as well -- for carriage return.

Comment: @jpaugh you can use any letter, such as `a`, if you want, it just depends on the value of `\newlinechar` which is 10 by default. using `^^M` is tricky even if you set `\newlinechar` to 13 as it is `\endlinechar` and acts like a comment hiding the rest of the input line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I had forgotten about the special character mappings TeX has.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. This solution does not seem to work for `mystrings` defined as follows: `\usepackage{xstring}
\def\mystrings{\noindent\StrSubstitute{%
B; new; test old; found people; sun; atom; number; life}%
{; }{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\newline}}
\mystrings`. Should I ask a new question for this?

Comment: @Krantz I can't see how that's related to the question or this answer, it doesn't use `^^J` at all.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. I will open a new question then.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. I would appreciate your help if possible: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699750/how-to-immediate-write-multiple-lines-produced-with-newline-and-strsubstitute. Thanks