# macros/commands inside a filecontents* environment does not expand

Tags: macros, filecontents

i would like to seek your help on the following.

Consider the following MWE1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Hi
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.tex}
some text and math here $A=s^2$
\end{filecontents*}
\end{document}
```

It works fine. An external file "dummy.tex" is created with the contents "some text and math here $A=s^2$".

Now, consider the following MWE2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\newcommand*{\somecommand}{some text and math here $A=s^2$}%
\begin{document}
Hi
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.tex}
\somecommand
\end{filecontents*}
\end{document}
```

An external file "dummy.tex" is also created, but with the contents "\somecommand". What I would want instead is for the file to contain "some text and math here $A=s^2$".

Now, consider the following MWE3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\newcommand*{\somecommandA}{some text and math here $A=s^2$}%
\newcommand*{\somecommandB}{5}%
\begin{document}
Hi
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.tex}
\somecommandA
\\
\ifthenelse{\equal{\somecommandB}{5}}{5}{4}
\end{filecontents*}
\end{document}
```

An external file "dummy.tex" is also created, but with the contents

```
\somecommandA
\\
\ifthenelse{\equal{\somecommandB}{5}}{5}{4}
```

What I would want instead is for the file to contain

```
some text and math here $A=s^2$
5
```

Is there a way we can put commands and macros inside the `filecontents*` environment, and have the external file contain the expanded commands and macros? (I understand `filecontents*` behave like verbatim.) If not `filecontents*`, is there another package/environment that can achieve this?

Kindly seeking your help. Thank you.

Comment: As you diagnosed yourself, `filecontents` reads things verbatim, so `\command` and `zcommand` are pretty much the same. It can be changed to make MWE2 work because `\somecommand` is a simple macro that expands to text. MWE3 is probably not possible (with a reasonable amount of effort, at least) because `\ifthenelse` does not “simply expand” to text.

Comment: thank you for the insight,   @PhelypeOleinik

Answer (score 6):

As you diagnosed yourself, `filecontents` reads things verbatim, so `\command` and `zcommand` are pretty much the same.

With a few changes, it can be changed to make MWE2 work because `\somecommand` is a simple macro that expands to text. For example, here's a `\filecontentsspecials<esc><bgroup><egroup>` macro, which makes the next `filecontents` environment use the character `<esc>` as escape character (usually `\`), `<bgroup>` as begin- and `<egroup>` as end-group characters (usually `{` and `}` respectively). **Important:** `\filecontentsspecials\\\{\}` will *not* work. The chosen characters cannot be any of `\\\{\}`. `|[]`, for example are valid.

After you use `\filecontentsspecials`, the next (and only the next) `filecontents` will carry out fill expansion of its contents, expanding macros. Things *not* to be expanded should be prefixed with `|noexpand` or wrapped in `|unexpanded[...]`. Here's the code:

```latex
\def\filecontentsspecials#1#2#3{
  \global\let\ltxspecials\dospecials
  \gdef\dospecials{\ltxspecials
    \catcode`#1=0
    \catcode`#2=1
    \catcode`#3=2
    \global\let\dospecials\ltxspecials
  }
}

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\somecommand}{some text and math here $A=s^2$}%
\begin{document}
Hi
\filecontentsspecials|[]
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{dummy.tex}
|somecommand % this expands
\somecommand % this does not
\end{filecontents*}
\end{document}
```

and the file will contain:

```
some text and math here $A=s^2$ % this expands
\somecommand % this does not
```

MWE3 is not possible (with a reasonable amount of effort, at least) because `\ifthenelse` does not “simply expand” to text.

Comment: hi @PhelypeOleinik. thank you for your response. for some reason (maybe my OS or my version of MikTeK), your MWE as is did not compile. thus, I modified your MWE a little bit. I included \usepackage{filecontents} after \documentclass{article}, and I removed the [overwrite] option, and your MWE compiled. thank you.

I'm still hoping, though, that I can put \ifthenelse and \renewcommand macros inside the filecontents* environment. the program I am making will need these macros expanding inside the filecontents* environment.

Comment: @beethovengg14 The `[overwrite]` option was introduced to `filecontents` in 19-10-01 (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511507/134574), so you'd need to update. But the modifications you made were correct. Now about `\renewcommand`: it won't work because the result of the command doesn't translate to simple text to be written (it does assignments, so it changes the state of TeX's memory), which means it doesn't “expand”, it “executes”. You won't be able to simply expand `\renewcommand` (or `\ifthenelse`, or _many_ other macros) into text to be written because they are not expandable.

Comment: @beethovengg14 (cont'd) You have three options: 1) Find another way around: depending on what you want to do you don't need to expand `\renewcommand` (it's quite unlikely, actually). 2) For the specific case of `\ifthenelse` with integers you can use `\ifnum\somecommandB=5 5\else 4\fi` (for other data types there are other better (and expandable) conditionals). 3) If you _absolutely_ need to expand `\renewcommand` you need to emulate TeX in TeX; there is one package, `unravel`, which does this, and it's 6000 lines of code, so you might want to reconsider 1 and 2. What is your aim?

Comment: hi @PhelypeOleinik, you've been very helpful. actually, i internalized your observations that some macros wouldn't really expand. so, i just used your code on \filecontentsspecials|[] and worked my way around using simple texts. but i will also follow your advice to update my filecontents.

Comment: @beethovengg14 Glad it helped :-) Note that the `filecontents` update I mentioned was introduced in the LaTeX kernel, so you have to update LaTeX itself, not only the `filecontents` package (if you use MiKTeX, you have to update the `latex-base` package, and if you use TeXLive 2019 or greater, doing `tlmgr update --all` should suffice)

Comment: Hi Phelype. Perhaps a little explanation of how you are doing this? In particular, I have no idea what your catcode manipulation is for.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Sorry for the delay. I change the definition of `\dospecials` to make the three characters (in the example `|`, `[` and `]`) mean the same as ``\``, `{` and `}` by changing their catcode to 0, 1 and 2, then revert back the original definition of `\dospecials`.  `\filecontentsspecials` is just a thin wrapper around that.  The catcode manipulation is because the varbatim-isation of `filecontents` makes the backslash be an ordinary character; thus you need something else.

Comment: Also by the way... from the look of it all the characters in `\end{filecontents*}` can't be used too (but who would accidentally choose one other than `\{}` anyway)