# Derive table data and TiKz lable from the same data source

Tags: pgfplotstable

I want to combine two of my posts to get a running example for my electrical installation plan in TikZ.

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709840/104358) post, I got the answer how to create a alphanumerical string with fixed length.

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709852/104358) post, I got the answer how to derive a dynamic table and a TikZ input just from one single data list.

Now I want to combine both topics and bring the generated alphanumerical string into my single data list. From there, the \hash within the dynamic table should be the same hash value than used as my TikZ label.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\sys_gset_rand_seed:n {0}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\hash}{}
 {
  \__new_hash_three:e { \int_to_Base:nn { \int_rand:n { 46655 } } { 36 } } % three digits
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__new_hash_three:n
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { 3 - \tl_count:n { #1 } } { 0 } #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__new_hash_three:n { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
id, name, x-coord, y-coord, rotation
\hash, PowerSupply1, 3590, 2000, 270 %The \hash function seems to be called twice
\hash, PowerSupply2, 5590, 2500, 270
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\CSVDataRows{\pgfplotsretval-1} 

\tikzset{
    pics/PowerSupply/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{PowerSupply/.cd, #1}
            \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt] (-p)
                {\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{example-image-a}};
            \node[
                inner sep=0pt,
                anchor={90+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/PowerSupply/label position}},
                rotate={-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/PowerSupply/label position}}
            ] at (-p.south) {\tiny \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/PowerSupply/label}};
        }
    },
    PowerSupply/label/.initial={},
    PowerSupply/label position/.initial={0}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    columns={id, name, x-coord, y-coord},
    columns/id/.style={
        column name=ID,
        string type
    },
    columns/name/.style={
        column name=Description,
        string type
    },
    columns/x-coord/.style={
        column name=X-Pos
    },
    columns/y-coord/.style={
        column name=Y-Pos,
        column type/.add={}{|}
    },
    column type/.add={|}{},
    after row={\hline},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline},
]{data.csv}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01mm, y=-0.01mm]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (ground_floor)   
        {\includegraphics[width=99.0mm, height=107.4mm]{example-image}};
    
    \begin{scope}[shift=(ground_floor.north west)]
        \foreach \row in {0,...,\CSVDataRows} {
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{x-coord}\of{\csvdata}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{y-coord}\of{\csvdata}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{rotation}\of{\csvdata}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{id}\of{\csvdata}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\i}{"\pgfplotsretval"}
            \pic[rotate=\r, transform shape] at (\x,\y) {
                PowerSupply={
                    label={\i}, % This label is different to the label in the table
                    label position={\r}
                }
            };
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image: Example]

**PROBLEM**
As you can see, the "shared" `\hash` from filecontents data list is different between the table representation and within the TikZ label. My assumption is, that the `\hash` function is called twice...

Comment: I am unsure why you would need to store hashes in your CSV which you then load again into your document. Why not just generating the hashes separately? You might want to store each hash in a separate macro or in some clist, so it does not change once it has been created.

Comment: The problem really is, that you store "`\hash`" in the CSV and not the generated hashes. So, when the file is read (which happens indeed twice), TeX reads `\hash` and finally expands this. You can look into the file and you will not see any hashes in there. What you want to do is to generate hashes and store these in your CSV in the first place.

Comment: See [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534044/47927) for a way to solve this.

Comment: Hmm I got your point. My idea was not to use a separate csv file, but have everything encapsulated within the LaTex file. The csv generation was just the workaround to feed two inputs (table & TikZ picture) with one single source of truth (filecontens list).

Comment: Maybe I have to rethink this approach again, but I hope that my idea behind this is clear now :) The answer you posted is still not clear for me. I thought that I don't have an issue with expanding the macro but do this twice...

Comment: Using [`pgfplotstable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) you don't necessarily need to use a CSV. You can also just put the data inline. Search for `\pgfplotstableread` in the documentation of the package to get some examples for different ways to read in data.

Comment: Actually, I like your questions. I don't use `pgfplotstable` that often and you stitch together a lot of interesting things! So it is nice to follow your thoughts and come up with solutions =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you store the string "`\hash`" in the CSV file and not the generated hashes. If you look into the CSV file, you won't find any hashes in there.

When the file is read in (which happens indeed twice), TeX encounters the token `\hash` and finally expands it. Because this expansion takes place first when the table is typeset and later again when the labels (= nodes) are typeset, the resulting hashes are not the same. In fact it is the same result as if you would have put `\hash` in your document four times.

From your comments I learned that you are not necessarily bound to use a CSV file. You just want to use the same data twice. You actually can just put the data inline without exporting them to a CSV. Anyways, you need to somehow make sure that the `\hash` commands are expanded before they are used for typsetting the table or the labels, so that the same token list (that is the expanded string) is used.

In the following example, I use `\pgfplotstableread` to read in the data inline. I then add a new column to the existing data using `\pgfplotstablecreatecol` which contains the expansion of the token list stored in the `id` column. In this case, the new column will then contain the expanded hashes. In the following code, I use the values from this new column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\sys_gset_rand_seed:n {0}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \hash } { } {
    \__new_hash_three:e { \int_to_Base:nn { \int_rand:n { 46655 } } { 36 } } % three digits
}
\cs_new:Nn \__new_hash_three:n {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 3 - \tl_count:n { #1 } } { 0 } #1
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__new_hash_three:n { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfplotstableread{
    id name x-coord y-coord rotation
    \hash{} PowerSupply1 3590 2000 270 
    \hash{} PowerSupply2 5590 2500 270
}{\mydata}

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \getthisrow{id}\idValue
        \edef\hashExp{\idValue}
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\hashExp
    }
]{id-exp}{\mydata}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mydata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\myDataRows{\pgfplotsretval-1} 

\tikzset{
    pics/PowerSupply/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{PowerSupply/.cd, #1}
            \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt] (-p)
                {\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{example-image-a}};
            \node[
                inner sep=0pt,
                anchor={90+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/PowerSupply/label position}},
                rotate={-1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/PowerSupply/label position}}
            ] at (-p.south) {\tiny \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/PowerSupply/label}};
        }
    },
    PowerSupply/label/.initial={},
    PowerSupply/label position/.initial={0}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    columns={id-exp, name, x-coord, y-coord},
    columns/id-exp/.style={
        column name=ID,
        string type
    },
    columns/name/.style={
        column name=Description,
        string type
    },
    columns/x-coord/.style={
        column name=X-Pos
    },
    columns/y-coord/.style={
        column name=Y-Pos,
        column type/.add={}{|}
    },
    column type/.add={|}{},
    after row={\hline},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline},
]{\mydata}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01mm, y=-0.01mm]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (ground_floor)   
        {\includegraphics[width=99.0mm, height=107.4mm]{example-image}};
    
    \begin{scope}[shift=(ground_floor.north west)]
        \foreach \row in {0,...,\myDataRows} {
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{x-coord}\of{\mydata}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{y-coord}\of{\mydata}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{rotation}\of{\mydata}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{id-exp}\of{\mydata}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\i}{"\pgfplotsretval"}
            \pic[rotate=\r, transform shape] at (\x,\y) {
                PowerSupply={
                    label={\i}, % This label is different to the label in the table
                    label position={\r}
                }
            };
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Made my Day! Thank you!! This is exactly what I searched for!