# \filecontents worked once but always with error messages. What should I do?

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, filesystem-access

I get error messages that don't make sense running code which I've adapted from https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/graphics/circuit_macros/doc/Circuit_macros.pdf.
I've rewritten the code with the built-in text editor in Ubuntu the "Text Editor" to be sure that I don't have hidden tokens from the copy/paste process and I have no tabs in the file. It worked once, don't know how. Should I re-install TexLive?
I've been running other Tikz stuff with no problem.

> LaTeX Warning: Writing file `./['.

> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H   for immediate help.

> l.4 \begin{filecontents*}[n

> ```
>                        oheader,force]{sample.m4}
> ```

When I rerun it I get the same missing `\begin{document}`complaint and it always error indicates the options bracket in `\filecontents`. If I delete the offending option it complains about the next.
It also gives me a warning:

> LaTeX Warning: File `[' already exists on the system.
> Not generating it from this source.

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mtotex[2]{\immediate\write18{m4 #2.m4 | dpic -#1 > #2.tex}}
\begin{filecontents*}[noheader,force]{sample1.m4}
include(pgf.m4)
.PS
cct_init
elen = 0.75
Origin: Here
    source(up_ elen); llabel(-,v_s,+)
    resistor(right_ elen); rlabel(,R,)
    dot
    {  
        capacitor(down_ to (Here,Origin))
        rlabel(+,v,-);llabel(,C,)
        dot
    }
    line right_ elen*3/3
    inductor(down_ Here.y-Origin.y); rlabel(,L,);b_current(i)
    line to Origin
.PE
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader,nosearch]{dummy.m4}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\mtotex{g}{sample1}
\begin{figure}[ht]
   \input{sample}
   \caption{customized caption}
   \label{Symbolic_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: What is the output of `pdflatex '\stop'`?  You probably has an older version of LaTeX that doesn't support the optional argument in `filecontents`

Comment: pdflatex '\stop'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.

Comment: The options to `filecontents` were introduced in [2019-10-01](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511507/134574), so your version of LaTeX doesn't support them.  You need to update (or use the `filecontents` package and `\begin{filecontents*}`, to get the same behaviour as `[noheader,force]`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You were right. Reinstalled. Now it complains
```((/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./testQ.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/sample/common/sample.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \starttext ```
          It came when I changed
```\begin{filecontents*}[noheader,force]{sample1.m4}```
to ```\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader,nosearch]{sample1.m4}``` I had error:
```)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of ^^M.
<inserted text> 
                \par

Comment: You seem to be executing a ConTeXt example file `context/sample/common/sample.tex`.  That won't work in LaTeX...

Comment: Thank you @PhelypeOleinik . It works! You're amazing! I had a typo. Should have done input on sample1.tex and not sample,tex which u say belongs to ConTeX. Don't know how I got ConTeX on my computer, as far as I know I've only installed TexLive
Then I forgot --shell-escape a couple of times.
```pdflatex --shell-escape testQ.tex```