# How to \immediate\write multiple lines produced using \newline and \StrSubstitute

Tags: pdftex, expansion, auxiliary-files, xstring, write

Why [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335211/how-to-immediate-write-with-multiple-lines) does not work when the lines are produced using `\newline` (instead of `^^J`) and `\StrSubstitute` as follows? Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\mystrings{\noindent\StrSubstitute{%
B; new; test old; found people; sun; atom; number; life}%
{; }{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\newline}}
\mystrings
% B
% new
% test old
% found people
% sun
% atom
% number
% life

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=mystrings.txt
\immediate\write\file{\mystrings}
\closeout\file

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\StrSubstitute` is not expandable, it won't work in \write.

Comment: Hi @Ulrike Fischer. Thank you. How can we solve this then? Any thoughts?

Comment: in expl3 are expandable commands, or you do the substitution first and only write the result string.

Comment: xstring commands generally are not expandable, also why use `\newline` here? that adds  some glue and penalties to affect tex's typesetting algorithms but doesn't do anything useful in a `\write`

Comment: Hi @ Ulrike Fischer @DavidCarlisle. Thank you. `newline` was added to replace `; ` with new line. And that does the job as you can see. The problem was when trying `write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want here but perhaps

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\def\mystrings{ B; new; test old; found people; sun; atom; number; life}%

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=mystrings.txt
{\newlinechar=`;
\immediate\write\file{\mystrings}
}
\closeout\file

\end{document}
```

which produces the file

```
 B
 new
 test old
 found people
 sun
 atom
 number
 life
```

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. Thank you very much. It works as expected. Well done.

Comment: @Krantz it's not adding space, you have them in the input, so simplest is to not have them in the input

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. Sure. Well done. Great work. I appreciate it greatly.